# How is possible that free memory goes down and used memory is not going up?

Tags: linux, monitoring, system-monitoring

I  am collecting the results of `free -m` command on an ubuntu server every 5 seconds, and preparing a time series graph based on the values of `free` and `used` columns.

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            992          43         709           5         238         791
Swap:           979
```

Sometimes the server that I am  monitoring has a pattern like below:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3jjN.png)

I do not understand how the free memory can go  down and used memory stay  constant. Can it be some swap happening or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Free memory means **unused** memory. Since this is a waste of resources the Linux kernel uses it to cache/buffer files: access to memory is much faster than access to disks.

In the output of `free` the total memory is divided into:

- **free** memory,
- **used** memory,
- **buff/cache**.

The **available** memory is what the system can use without killing applications or swapping.

Comment: Thank you for the  reply. I will log the available value also and next week check the graph again. Right now as  mentioned am using only free and available columns from free -m output. I am really curious to see the difference between free and available at different points of time.